# How to get the clicked value of the button in the telegram robot

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

Using telegram's robot function, when entering /begin, pop-up button selection (for example: Jasmine, Strawberry, Geranium...), after clicking, the robot returns the clicked value, now I don't know how to get it, How should the following code be written, I hope I can get help, please.

Here is the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjLZy.png) and my code

```
bot.command("begin", (ctx) => {
  return ctx.reply("please select ", {
    reply_markup: {
      keyboard: [
        ["Jasmine", "Strawberry"],
        ["Geranium", "Lavender", "Sunflower"],
      ],
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true,
    },
  });
});
```

I looked up and think it should be ReplyKeyboardMarkup, and some others like Markup.keyboard(), but I'm not sure.

P.S This is just a similar picture I found online, hacked and deleted